# Errors during downloading metadata for repository 'AppStream'

Tags: yum, centos8

When I use `yum list java*`,I get an error like the following：

```
[root@crucialer ~]# yum list java*
Repository extras is listed more than once in the configuration
Repository centosplus is listed more than once in the configuration
CentOS-8 - AppStream                                                                                                                                                           17 kB/s | 2.3 kB     00:00
Errors during downloading metadata for repository 'AppStream':
  - Status code: 404 for http://mirrors.cloud.aliyuncs.com/centos/8/AppStream/x86_64/os/repodata/repomd.xml (IP: 100.100.2.148)
Error: Failed to download metadata for repo 'AppStream': Cannot download repomd.xml: Cannot download repodata/repomd.xml: All mirrors were tried
```

```
[root@crucialer ~]# ping 100.100.2.148
PING 100.100.2.148 (100.100.2.148) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 100.100.2.148: icmp_seq=1 ttl=102 time=1.94 ms
64 bytes from 100.100.2.148: icmp_seq=2 ttl=102 time=1.88 ms
64 bytes from 100.100.2.148: icmp_seq=3 ttl=102 time=2.08 ms
64 bytes from 100.100.2.148: icmp_seq=4 ttl=102 time=1.94 ms
64 bytes from 100.100.2.148: icmp_seq=5 ttl=102 time=1.93 ms
^C
--- 100.100.2.148 ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 5 received, 0% packet loss, time 8ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 1.883/1.953/2.078/0.076 ms
[root@crucialer ~]# ping www.baidu.com
PING www.a.shifen.com (180.101.49.12) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 180.101.49.12 (180.101.49.12): icmp_seq=1 ttl=50 time=15.6 ms
64 bytes from 180.101.49.12 (180.101.49.12): icmp_seq=2 ttl=50 time=15.2 ms
64 bytes from 180.101.49.12 (180.101.49.12): icmp_seq=3 ttl=50 time=15.2 ms
64 bytes from 180.101.49.12 (180.101.49.12): icmp_seq=4 ttl=50 time=15.3 ms
^C
--- www.a.shifen.com ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 6ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 15.223/15.331/15.581/0.210 ms
```

```
[root@crucialer yum.repos.d]# cat CentOS-Base.repo
# CentOS-Base.repo
#
# The mirror system uses the connecting IP address of the client and the
# update status of each mirror to pick mirrors that are updated to and
# geographically close to the client.  You should use this for CentOS updates
# unless you are manually picking other mirrors.
#
# If the mirrorlist= does not work for you, as a fall back you can try the
# remarked out baseurl= line instead.
#
#
[base]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Base - 163.com
#mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&repo=os
baseurl=http://mirrors.163.com/centos/$releasever/os/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=http://mirrors.163.com/centos/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-7

#released updates
[updates]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Updates - 163.com
#mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&repo=updates
baseurl=http://mirrors.163.com/centos/$releasever/updates/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=http://mirrors.163.com/centos/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-7

#additional packages that may be useful
[extras]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Extras - 163.com
#mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&repo=extras
baseurl=http://mirrors.163.com/centos/$releasever/extras/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=http://mirrors.163.com/centos/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-7

#additional packages that extend functionality of existing packages
[centosplus]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Plus - 163.com
baseurl=http://mirrors.163.com/centos/$releasever/centosplus/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
enabled=0
gpgkey=http://mirrors.163.com/centos/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-7
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Pierz has rightly pointed. I would like to add few commands that change the repo to vault.centos.org

```
# sed -i 's/mirrorlist/#mirrorlist/g' /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-*
# sed -i 's|#baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org|baseurl=http://vault.centos.org|g' /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-*
```

Now run the command: yum list java*

Answer (score 1):

This is probably down to the fact that [CentOS Linux 8 has reached End Of Life](https://www.centos.org/centos-linux-eol/). The linked article explains that you if want keep with CentoOS8 you'll need to change the repos to use vault.centos.org BUT there will be no further updates. If you want maintain updates you should migrate to Centos Stream to - one way to do this:

```
sudo dnf --disablerepo '*' --enablerepo=extras swap centos-linux-repos centos-stream-repos
sudo dnf distro-sync
```

Also looking at your config it seems you have some references to Centos7 which might interfere with things, though hopefully the update will deal with them. Note: [CentOS7 is supported till 2024-06-30](https://wiki.centos.org/About/Product).

---